# Python 3 - Alphabetical index finder

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

I really need help on where to start this function for my program. This is basically what I have to make it do!

It two parameters...The first parameter is a string representing a name. The second parameter is a list of strings in alphabetical order.

The function returns an integer indicating the position or index in the list of names such that if you inserted the given name string into the list at that index the list would still be in alphabetical order.

I tried asking in another spot about this I believe but I phrased it a little wrong. I am new here so not too sure on working the site!

Thank you for any help, much appreciated! Here is how I started my function:

```
def find_position(name, stringslist):    
    for line in stringslist:
        newlist = line.split(",")
        if newlist[0] =
```

The function does not insert the name, or change any of the current names. It just returns where the new name should be inserted.

The data in the file currently is setup like this on every line:

Name,data,data
Yellow fin,4.05,17.0

Thank you again!

Comment: If possible try to include some sample inputs for the parameters and an example would be better to understand.

Comment: Thank you Tranveer! I just added some more info on how the file is structured.

Answer (score 1):

You can use naive linear search which is O(n) time complexity:

```
def find_position(s, l):
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        if s <= e:
            return i
    return len(l)
```

Or an O(log n) algorithm with the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module:

```
def find_position(s, l):
    from bisect import bisect_left
    return bisect_left(l, s)
```

In case you can't use the `bisect` module, its functionality can be mimicked by implementing [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), but the efficiency of the algorithm may be insignificant if you aren't working with a large list of names.